# Why does the NetworkX graph not draw in Cygwin?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, cygwin, networkx

I am running Python and NetworkX (a graphing library) on Cygwin (Windows 7).

The following code creates a graph and attempts to draw it - but nothing appears on screen:

```
plt.ion()
nx.draw(nx.petersen_graph())
plt.show()
```

There don't appear to be any errors.

I have also tried saving a graph to an image using:

```
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

which creates the correct image.

Does this have to do with matplotlib and Cygwin?

Comment: do you have an interactive backend installed?

Comment: @tcaswell Does that mean matplotlib or pyplot? If so, then yes both are installed and work in other applications.

Comment: Silly question but how are you running this code? Is it from the command line or an interactive python shell like IPhyton or through some IDE like PyScripter? If so you need to turn interactive mode on see: http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_use_Matplotlib_with_PyScripter_?

Comment: Are you using `TkAgg`, `gtkagg` on `qtagg`?

Comment: @tcaswell My backend was set to 'agg'.

Comment: @EdChum I was under the impression that `plt.ion()` turns interactive mode on?

Comment: the `agg` backend does not include an interactive part (it knows nothing about how to draw to a gui), you need to use one of the interactive backends.

Comment: I've got it working, thanks to both of you. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by:

1. Starting X using `startxwin` and running the script from there.
2. Changing the `backend = agg` setting to `backend = tkagg` in my matplotlibrc file.

Thanks to `tcaswell` and `EdChum` for the help.